# OverflowError in python?

Tags: python, overflow

there is an OverflowError: int too large to convert to float at

```
l = (number // 10)*n
```

what does it mean and how to solve it?

that's the entire code

```
def main():
    count = 0
    n = 10
    t = int(input())
    arr = []
    for i in range(t):
        number = int (input())
        print(number)
        while number != 0:
            l = (number // 10)*n
            print(l)
            if l != 0:
                count += 1
                arr.append(l)
            number = number / 10
            n = n * 10
        print(count)
        print(arr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It means what it says: "int too large to convert to float"

Comment: but when I replace 'n' with a number it gets the desired output without any errors, and 'n' is only there to be multiplied by 10 each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `while` loop is running , value change in number does not effect on `while` condition. so you have to `break` loop using `if-else`.

```
def main():
    count = 0
    n = 10
    t = int(input())
    arr = []
    for i in range(t):
        number = int (input())
        print(number)
        while True:
            l = (number // 10)*n
            print(l)
            if l != 0:
                count += 1
                arr.append(l)
            number = number / 10
            n = n * 10
            if int(number) == 0:
                break
        print(count)
        print(arr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
2
25
25
20
0.0
1
[20]
```